# how to reset jqgrid after refreshing its data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I'm refreshing jqgrid with this script:

```
$('#btnRefresh').click(function () {
   $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/General/ProvinceLoadGrid.json",
      success: function (data) {
           if (data != null) {
               jQuery('#dataTable').jqGrid('clearGridData')
                     .jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: data, page: 1})
                     .trigger('reloadGrid');
           }
      }
   });
)};
```

I have configured jqgrid to save selected rows after moving through pages.
this script triggers reload grid to reload data, but this produces a problem.
the problem is when I select first row in the page 1, (when each page has 10 records)
the first record on the second page (11th record) is selected too. also the record on the 3rd page is selected too (21st record) etc ...
all of this happens after reloadGrid. the jqgrid is saving my selection on each page correctly, but after reload grid this problem occurs.

How can I manage to solve this?

Comment: Thanks Lithium.
I change my data type to local for client side refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it !
the problem is after reload grid the datatype resets to its default value and we need to set it back to json or xml again!

```
$('#btnRefresh').click(function () {
   $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/General/ProvinceLoadGrid.json",
      success: function (data) {
           if (data != null) {
               jQuery('#dataTable').jqGrid('clearGridData')
                     .jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: data, datatype: 'json'})
                     .trigger('reloadGrid');
           }
      }
   });
)};
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if (data != null) {
 jQuery('#dataTable').jqGrid('clearGridData')
 jQuery('#dataTable').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: data, page: 1})
 jQuery('#dataTable').trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

Comment: I was using these code, before the one I'm using now. there's no difference between them

Comment: I also clear the array which save's selected rows through pages. but doesn't make any difference. it is because of that when page loads, loadComplete of jqgrid occurs and select's nothing. when I move through pages the loadComplete updates the array it uses to save selection and selects rows. after refresh, loadComplete considers all pages as page 1. and this is why when I select first row in page 1, all first rows in other pages get selected too

Comment: @Lithium: that is the different issue. you need to modify row selector to restrict to first page.

Comment: this code updates array to select rows:/
var updateIdsOfSelectedRows = function (id, isSelected) {
var index = $.inArray(id, idsOfSelectedRows);
if (!isSelected && index >= 0) {
idsOfSelectedRows.splice(index, 1);
} else if (index < 0) {
idsOfSelectedRows.push(id);
}
};

and on loadComplete I used: 
var $this = $(this), i , count;
for (i = 0, count = idsOfSelectedRows.length; i< count; i++) {
$(this).jqGrid('setSelection', idsOfSelectedRows[i], false);
}
}

Comment: $("#jqGridAsistencia").jqGrid('clearGridData');
              $("#jqGridAsistencia").jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: gridArrayData});
              $("#jqGridAsistencia")[0].grid.endReq();
              $("#jqGridAsistencia").trigger('reloadGrid');

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all problems,I do this

> Html - enclose jQgrid table in a div

```
<div id="tableDivID">
  <table id="tableID"></table>
  <div id="tablePagerID"></div>
</div>
```

> Jquery - Function for activating jQgrid

```
function activatejQGrid(data)
{

$("tableID").jQGrid({
//code for jQgrid initilise with *data*
}}

}
```

**re-initialise jQgrid**

```
$("#tableDivID").replaceWith(function () {
  return "<div id='tableDivID'><table id='tableID'></table><div id='tablePagerID'></div>
</div>";
  });
activatejQGrid(data);
```